# Make SUM of Column value of all row up to current row in SSRS

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have webapplication having SSRS Reports...

I have a situation where i have to Update sum of particular field into last column for all above row up to current row..

for example..

```
ID    Balance    Total
----------------------
1     100        100      
2     200        300  
3      10        310
4    -100        210
5     200        410
```

In Above table, last column `Total` makes sum of value of `Balance` column  of all above rows..
how can i achieve this ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `RunningValue` expression for this sort of thing, see:

[RunningValue Function (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255229.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

This works for your data and example:

[image]

A simple table based on this:

[image]

The **Total** expression is:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Balance.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

Which gives the expected results:

[image]

Depending on your exact setup, you may need to change the *Scope* parameter to a **Group** or **Dataset** value, but `Nothing` works in the typical case.

Comment: Did this answer help your issue at all?